# rstudio rerun with debug can't test with objects in the environment

Tags: r, debugging

I try to debug with my code
And when error occurs,it shows me some options to click at the right of the error message.
[image]

However,when I click rerun with debug, it stop at the function like stop(...) in the bottom of calling stack.

I can see the variables if I click the call stack in the right "traceback" panel

But I can't do anything with those temp var in functions, it tells me that var can't get found.If I click next or type in n, it will quit the debug mode.

So this 'rerun with debug' button can only trace me back to the scene to witness what happened and I can't do any self-test to see what really happened?

Comment: I would suggest to set a ˋbrowser()ˋ just before where the error occurred and source your code/package again (`pkgload::load_all()ˋ). Then, you can investigate.

Comment: @layal sure,but I was wondering rerun with debug can't do anything useful here?

Comment: Personally, I do not use rerun with debug to debug things. I rather use browser(). See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html for more options.